# Mockito and Android: Check if the order button its working

Tags: android, junit, mockito

My activity has a ListView, the user can order the list by pressing a button.
I want to test if this feature is working as I expect. So, I decided to create Mockito test.

What I have so far:

```
@Test
public void checkIfOrderAscendingIsWorking() throws Exception {
    // generate random users
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    for (int i = 0; i< QUANTITY_USERS_TO_TEST; i++){
        users.add(generateRandomUser(i+1));
    }

    mListUserView.displayUsers(users);
    mUserPresenter.sortUsers(true);

    // sort the users to compare
    Collections.sort(users, new Comparator<User>() {
        public int compare(User lhs, User rhs) {
            return lhs.name.compareToIgnoreCase(rhs.name);
        }
    });
  // How can I compare both lists? 
}
```

So, How can I compare the listview user list to my local user list? What is the best practice to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get the sorted users from the `mUserPresenter` object. 
Something like:

```
List<User> sortedUsers = mUserPresenter.getUsers();
```

I you are not able to do this, you could create a getter in that object.

Then you could simply iterate over both list and run the asserts:

```
for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
  assertEquals(users.get(i), sortedUsers.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help. I created this method on my view: public List<User> getUsers() {
        return mUsersAdapter.getItems();
    }

and then, created on my presenter: public List<User> getUsers(){
        return mView.getUsers();
    }

But when I call the presenter method on Mockito, it's returning empty .

Comment: Ok, I think my problem is the presenter need to return the list of users and not the view, that's correct?

Answer (score 0):

1) Save your list on your presenter

2) Add this code:

```
@Test
public void checkIfOrderAscendingIsWorking() throws Exception {
    // generate random users
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    for (int i = 0; i< QUANTITY_USERS_TO_TEST; i++){
        users.add(generateRandomUser(i+1));
    }

   mUserPresenter.displayUsers(new ArrayList(users)); // avoid reference
    mUserPresenter.sortUsers(true);

    // sort the users to compare
    Collections.sort(users, new Comparator<User>() {
        public int compare(User lhs, User rhs) {
            return lhs.name.compareToIgnoreCase(rhs.name);
        }
    });
  Assert.assertThat(mUserPresenter.getUsers(),
            IsIterableContainingInOrder.contains(users.toArray()));
}
```